# Use `before` or `require` in Puppet manifests?

Tags: puppet

Okay, I just started learning Puppet and working through the docs. From what I see:

- `require` does the same as `before`
- `subscribe` does the same as `notify`

Obviously these are added at opposite sides of the dependency relationship, but you get my point.

From a code readability and maintainability aspect, is using one (of each pair) better than the other? Should I use both for maximum clarity or would this make the maintenance cumbersome? Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either variant works equally fine. They have some concrete uses though.

- Make intentions more clear

E.g.

```
exec { "initialize-footool": require => Package["footool"] }
file { "/etc/default/footool": before => Exec["initialize-footool"] }
```

read more like english than just requires on the exec.

- Build relations to other resources that don't know about the resource in question

E.g.

```
include apache
exec { "apache2ctl graceful": require => Package[apache] } # package inside class apache
```

The latter is pretty bad practice though. I found that one of the most definite benefits lie in these metaparameters' ability to target whole classes instead.

```
include apache
exec { "apache2ctl graceful": require => Class["apache"] }
file { "/etc/default/apache2": before => Class["apache"] }
```

People who are intent on limiting themselves to, say, `require` instead of ever using `before` **can** resort to this syntax

```
class { "apache": require => File["/etc/default/apache2"] }
```

The community discourages class {} style declarations though, because

- it cannot be used to declare the same class more than once
- it imposes parse order issues even when mixed with `include` statements for the same class

Comment: So my reading of this is essentially, "Use what you need to best maintain modularity." Is that pretty much correct?

Comment: That is a sound summation, yes.